# Action not found in Route table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

Just started my first MVC 2.0 .net application.  And I set up some default pages like:

```
/Loa/Register
/Loa/About
```

But when I request for `/Loa/sdfqsdf` (random string) I get the `"The resource cannot be found."` error, how can I redirect this non-existing action to a default action?

Like an "action not found" default action?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using routes

You can define more than one route (which is also quite common in real-life MVC applications), because some routes have particular settings that differ from the default one. And especially if you want to do decent SEO.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = string.Empty },
    new { action = "Register|Index|About" } // route constraint that limits the actions that can be used with this route
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "InvalidRoutes"
    "{*dummy}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Nonexisting" }
);
```

If you'll add additional routes to our route table, just make sure the `InvalidRoutes` is defined as the last one.

Comment: I didn't knew "{*dummy}" was possible, Thanks!

Comment: Anything's possible. For those parts that you want defaults, you can set them, for others that you don't you can easily omit them. In my example, `dummy` doesn't have a default and it will be set to anything you will be accessing.